# Kolmogorov: question on definition of Independence from his book

Tags: probability-theory, math-history

I'm reading [Kolmogorov Foundations of the Theory of Probability](https://archive.org/details/foundationsofthe00kolm), Page 9, which explains Independence and have questions.  Kolmogorov provides the following pictured *Definition I* for independence.  The definition is similar to what more modern books provide with exception to the inclusion of the experiment number.

The definition is confusing because an experiment $U^{(n)}$ is a decomposition of events.  A decomposition is a set of disjoint sets such that when union is taken, the result is $E$.  Kolmogorov typically uses $q_1, q_2, ..., q_n$ typically to denote elementary events (of the sample space).  From what I read, the definition implies that the intersection of an element from each experiment's decomposition.

My questions, is above explanation correct?  If so, *Definition I* is $= 0$ because an intersection of elementary events $A^{(1)}_{q_1} \cap A^{(1)}_{q_2} \cap ....\cap A^{(n)}_{q_n} = P(0) = 0$.  I think I have read something wrong, because there should be the possibility that these events intersect

Appreciate any guidance on understanding of Kolmogorov's grammatical and symbolic explanation of independence mentioned here.

[image: a]
[image: b]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A_{q_i}^{(i)}$ isn't an elementary event - it's some set of events.

Each experiment $\mathfrak{A}^{(i)}$ is a decomposition of $E$ into sets $A_j^{(i)}$. Sets say $A_{q_1}^{(1)}$ and $A_{q_2}^{(2)}$ are from different decompositions, so they can intersect.

Comment: Do you know what is meant by assigning $r = r_1 r_2 ... r_n$ probabilities?  Does he mean to suggest something multiplicative or is this just a set?

Comment: $p_{q_1 q_2 ... q_n}$ notation is also ambiguous.  Is it a single value?$

Comment: $r$ is number of ways all experiments can theoretically go, and it's product of numbers each experiment can go. $p_{q_1, \ldots, q_n}$ is a number - probability of getting result $q_1$ from 1st experiment and $q_2$ from 2nd and so on.

Comment: Later on the page he uses $p_{q_1 ... q_n}$ in a summation, so that is confusing.  Is it still a single value of probability used there?

Comment: $q_1, q_2, \ldots$ are variables. For each allowed value of them, $p_{q_1,q_2,\ldots}$ is a real number.

Comment: In the summation of $p_{q_1 ... q_n}$ is a real number just summed $q_1, ... , q_n$ times?  That doesn't seem to agree

Comment: No. $q_1, q_2, \ldots$ are indices. It can help to think about $p$ as a function with $n$ arguments $p(q_1, \ldots, q_n)$, just with arguments written in index instead of parentheses.

Comment: So the summation is binding a set of indices to the function $p$?  I wonder why he didn't just use a function

Comment: also, if $p_{q_1 q_2 ... q_n} = 1$ when indices are substituted, how can the above expression be $< 1$, when he claims $>= 0$

Comment: It's just standard notation - like we denote sequence terms as $x_i$, not $x(i)$. And no, $p_{q_1 q_2\ldots q_n\}$ isn't necessary $1$, why do you think it is?

Comment: It appears $p_{q_1 q_2 ... q_n}$ (depending on the indices) is assigned probabilities for all ordered arrangements with repetition of the events from each decomposition.  The sum of probability of all arrangements must equal 1.  Is this correct?  Practically, I'm unsure how one would assign a value to $p_{q_1 q_2 ... q_n}$ maybe I need to read more

Comment: There are no repetitions - we just fix what happened in each experiment and then check probability of such result. Say that first experiment gives result either $a$ or $b$, second - $c, d, e$, third - $f, g$. I.e. $q_1 \in \{a, b\}$ and so on. Then $p_{acf}$ if probability of getting $a$ in the first experiment, $c$ in second and $f$ in third.

Comment: Ok $p_{acf}$ understood.  I was thinking of the case where the decomposition of sets is the same for each experiment and $A^{(1)}_{q_1} \cap A^{(2)}_{q_2}$ is a repeat of the same elementary events.  I suspect in such a case each $E = A^{(1)}_{1} \cup ... \cup A^{(i)}_{r_i}, i = 1, 2, ... n$ may have a different probability for each experiment.

Comment: I added a follow up Kolmogorov question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936166/kolmogorov-question-on-experiment-independence-using-his-theory.